# Using Find to return values using a condition based on a related model

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I have a **Company** model which is related to a **MonthlyReturn** model. A company can have many MonthlyReturns. I am trying to get an array of all companies which have a monthly return for a specified month.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
$this->Company->find('all', array('contain' => array(
    'MonthlyReturn' => array(
        'conditions' => array('MonthlyReturn.month' => "2012-01-01")
    )
)));
```

**The Company Model:**

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Employee' => array(
            'className' => 'Employee',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'MonthlyReturn' => array(
            'className' => 'MonthlyReturn',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

    public $hasOne = 'Umuser';

}
```

This code is returning all companies rather than those with a return for the month. The 'MonthlyReturn.month' field will always be in the format above, i.e year and month will change but will always be the 1st of the month.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: i think its hard to give a perfect answer without knowing the Company datamodel, but i will give it a try ;)

Comment: the containable behavior is also available?

Comment: Sorry @alexdd55, I don't understand your question? Can you elaborate please.

Comment: did you ad this  

public $actsAs = array(
        'Containable',
    );

Answer (score 0):

your code says, that you ask for a specific date, not a month.

try this:

```
$this->Company->find('all', array('contain' => array(
'MonthlyReturn' => array(
    'conditions' => array('MonthlyReturn.month LIKE' => "2012-01%")
))));
```

Comment: I have update my initial post now and as you will see the date will be in a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a better way but you can do it in two calls like this:

```
$company_ids = $this->MonthlyReturn->query("SELECT DISTINCT company_id FROM monthy_returns WHERE month = '2012-01-01';")

$this->Company->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Company.id' => $company_ids[0]),
    'contain' => array('MonthlyReturn' => array(
        'conditions' => array('MonthlyReturn.month' => "2012-01-01")
    )
)));
```

That's the idea but **some debugging may be required**